# React leaflet marker layer not updating on zoom

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

The `react-leaflet-marker-layer` does not update on zooming the map in/out.

It stays the same, while the map content changes its zoom level.

This happens both during zoom using mouse scroll and the +/- buttons.

NOTE: This may be related, I noticed the map rendering is very slow and some tiles take very long to load. Zooming in/out helps to load them instantly.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Map, Marker, Popup, TileLayer } from 'react-leaflet';
import MarkerLayer from 'react-leaflet-marker-layer';

const position = { lng: -122.673447, lat: 45.522558 };
const markers = [
  {
    position: { lng: -122.67344700000, lat: 45.522558100000 },
    text: 'Voodoo Doughnut',
  },
  {
    position: { lng: -122.67814460000, lat: 45.5225512000000 },
    text: 'Bailey\'s Taproom',
  },
  {
    position: { lng: -122.67535700000002, lat: 45.5192743000000 },
    text: 'Barista'
  },
  {
    position: { lng: -122.65596570000001, lat: 45.5199148000001 },
    text: 'Base Camp Brewing'
  }
];

class ExampleMarkerComponent extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const style = {
      border: 'solid 1px lightblue',
      backgroundColor: '#333333',
      borderRadius: '50%',
      marginTop: '-5px',
      marginLeft: '-5px',
      width: '10px',
      height: '10px'
    };

    return (
      <div style={Object.assign({}, this.props.style, style)}></div>
    );
  }

}

class MapView extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
                  <div
                    style={{
                        height:"700px"
                    }}>
                    <Map center={position} zoom={13}
                        style={{
                            height:"700px"
                        }}>
                        <TileLayer
                          url='http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
                          attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                        />
                        <MarkerLayer
                            markers={markers}
                            longitudeExtractor={m => m.position.lng}
                            latitudeExtractor={m => m.position.lat}
                            markerComponent={ExampleMarkerComponent} />
                      </Map>
                  </div>
        );
    }
}

module.exports = MapView;
```

[image: Combined screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this issue. Seems like the developer didn't add some event hadlers dor these casese. Not sure if this was intended, but looks more like a bug. The module version at this moment is 0.0.3, so I would't expect much from it.
You can actually just override the method, that sets the event handlers for the layer.

```
class MarkerLayer extends MapLayer {
    attachEvents () {
        const map = this.props.map;
        map.on('viewreset', () => this.updatePosition());
        map.on('zoom', () => this.updatePosition());
        map.on('zoomlevelschange', () => this.updatePosition());
    }
}
```

Now, if you use MarkerLayer class, markers would saty where they belong

Comment: Also, maybe it depends on the leaflet version you're using